# How can I change the class of an <li> when I click on an address inside that <li>

Tags: angularjs

I have a series

```
<li class=""><a href ng:click="a=1">A1</a></li>
<li class=""><a href ng:click="a=2">A2</a></li>
<li class=""><a href ng:click="a=3">A3</a></li>
```

Is there a way I can make the class of the li change to `<li class="current">` 
if a user clicks on any of the three `<li>` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)

```
<li ng-class="{current: a == 1}"><a href ng:click="a=1">A1</a></li>
<li ng-class="{current: a == 2}"><a href ng:click="a=2">A2</a></li>
<li ng-class="{current: a == 3}"><a href ng:click="a=3">A3</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<li class="{{a==1 && 'current'}}"><a href ng:click="a=1">A1</a></li>
<li class="{{a==2 && 'current'}}"><a href ng:click="a=2">A2</a></li>
<li class="{{a==3 && 'current'}}"><a href ng:click="a=3">A3</a></li>
```

Comment: So can I just confirm if I click on the first link then this will make the class of the first li equal to "current"?

Comment: I am just wondering. Do you think it's good or should I use the ng-class. I'm a bit confused now as I see two solutions that both work.

Comment: You can use either of the two. I would suggest using ng-class though :D